# CSS line-height question

Tags: css

What is the ideal line-height and what type of value should I use with line-height values, em, px or percentages?

Answer (score 4):

`em` is relative and will scale nicely when/if your users change the text size (which my mom, for example, often does for readability reasons).

Answer (score 4):

It is usually considered for a comfortable reading experience that line height should be 1.5 to 2 times the size of the font.

```
p{
font: normal 10pt/15pt sans-serif;
}
```

Note that it depends on the font you use. In web design, every rule has to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: I agree with @pixeline statement. Usually, the line-height is around **1.5** but it **depends on the font** you use. Besides the px, em, and percentages you can use **unitless values**. You would benefit from learning more about the [line-height property](https://kolosek.com/css-line-height/).

Answer (score 4):

A lot of people tend to use 1.2-1.5 [em](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)) as this is relative to your font size and had a nice 'look' to it. I am sure a typographer could explain more fully where those values come from.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex points out, you should use em, percent or whole numbers for line-height so it scales well. See [line-height on the Mozilla Developer's Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height) reference for further explanation.

```
p{
 font: normal 10pt/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ideal line-height is 1.3.](http://www.metamorphosite.com/CSS-font-styles-color-margin-padding-a-inline-code#Line_height)

Note that I [didn't use a unit for that.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/)